# Given 3 Groups A, B, C and 36 Students, how many ways are there to make groups, so that none is empty?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Given 3 Groups $A, B, C$ and $36$ Students, how many ways are there to make groups, so that none is empty?

My approach is to substract the illegal combinations (e.g. $A = 0, B = 1, C = 35$) from all possible combinations ($3^{36})$.

The illegal combinations are the following, given in tuples (A, B, C):
$$(0, 0, 36)$$
$$(0, 36, 0)$$
$$(36, 0, 0)$$
$$x:(0, 1, 35)-(0, 35, 1) $$
$$y:(1, 0, 35)-(35, 0, 1) $$
$$y:(1, 35, 0)-(35, 1, 0) $$
for $x,y$ and $z$ there are 36 combinations each.

In total this would come out to $3^{36}-(1+1+1+36+36+36) = 150.094.635.296.999.016
$

This is apparently wrong, the solution is supposedly $|\{1,2,3\}|! \cdot S_{36, |\{A,B,C\}|} = 205887910869180$. Can someone point out *why* mine is wrong and how you would approach it?

EDIT: I recalculated their solution given their way of calculating it and it indeed is $150.094.429.138.568.916$

Comment: You sure the solution has $20,588,791,086$? I have the solution [evaluates to](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=6%28S2%2836%2C3%29%29) $150,094,429,138,568,916$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution is $$k!S(n,k)$$

(your setup being $k=3,n=36$) since the Stirling numbers of the second kind, $S(n,k)$, precisely enumerate the ways to partition a set of $n$ labelled objects into $k$ nonempty unlabelled subsets. Hence, multiplying the Stirling numbers by $k!$ enumerates the ways to partition $n$ labelled objects into $k$ nonempty *labelled* subsets.

In general, we have the following identity:

$$k!S(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i}{k\choose i}(k-i)^n.\quad (1)$$

Let's try to see how $(1)$ is obtained in your setup (you can then derive it more generally).

If you notice, the first term of the sum in $(1)$ is $k^n$ (in your case $3^{36})$, which is, as you point out, the number of all possible assignments (allowing for empty groups). The problem is you didn't properly exclude all illegal assignments. You have to use [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

1. From the total assignments (of which there are $3^{36}$), we must subtract out the assignments that leave a particular group empty. There are $3$ particular groups that we may force to be empty, and having chosen the empty group, there are $(3-1)^{36}$ ways to assign $36$ people to the other two groups. Thus, we enumerate the number of such assignments as $3(3-1)^{36}.$
2. The enumeration from step 1 double counts assignments that leave two particular groups empty. Thus, we must add those back in. There are $3\choose 2$ ways we can force $2$ groups to be empty and having chosen the two empty groups, there are $(3-2)^{36}$ ways to assign the $36$ people to the nonempty group. Thus, the number of such assignments is ${3\choose 2}(3-2)^{36}.$

Thus, the solution is $3^{36}-3(3-1)^{36}+{3\choose 2}(3-2)^{36}$ in agreement with $(1).$

Answer (score 2):

For putting *distinct* objects into *distinct* boxes, you can simply apply the principle of inclusion-exclusion, thus

Total ways - at least one box empty + at least two boxes empty

$= 3^{36} - \binom31\cdot2^{36} + \binom32\cdot1^{36} =150\, 094\, 429\, 138\, 568\, 916$

Idk how the supposedly correct answer was obtained